# How to check wordpress plugins installed date and time

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I would like to see the word press installed plugins date and time. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: wordpress do not save date, time when plugin was installed, unless you find plugin for that. But it will not work for already activated plugins.

Comment: Would have been better if in WP core itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through this plugin, hope it will satisfies you

[plugin-activation-date](http://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-activation-date/)

Thanks

Comment: @Sampath you have to just reinstall all the plugins.

Comment: Reason 1,293 why I hate Wordpress. You need a plugin to know about your plugins. Is there really no way directly to see a timestamp of install date? Maybe a sql query?

Comment: This appears to work with modern versions of Wordpress, even though it is 10+ years old I think. It appears to only show anything that was activated after this was installed. It would be nice if it would read the Folder Date/Times. But it should help.

Answer (score 10):

**The only way** (till date):

- Go to `FTP>wp-content/plugins/`
- check the date of creation the folder (or files in it)